# python multiprocessing class

Tags: python, class, python-multiprocessing

I met with strange python behavior with this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import multiprocessing
import time
import sys

class worker(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, val):
        super(worker,self).__init__()
        self.val = val

    def update_val(self,val):
        self.val = val
        print("self.val now is %s" %(self.val))

    def run(self):
        while True:
            print("Worker report: val is %s" % (self.val))
            time.sleep(self.val)


subproc = worker(10)
subproc.start()
while True:
    new_val =  sys.stdin.readline().rstrip()
    if new_val:
        subproc.update_val(new_val)
    print("Main report: val is %s" % (subproc.val))
```

I desired, that variable `val` in object `subproc` was be changed by `update_val` function.
But I was surprised, because that variable was changed only for queries from `main` process.
Function `run` was still use old value:

```
$ ./test.py
Worker report: val is 10
Worker report: val is 10
5
self.val now is 5
Main report: val is 5

Main report: val is 5
Worker report: val is 10
Worker report: val is 10
```

What can be a problem cause? This code works similar in **Python2.7** and **Python3.6**. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Working code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import multiprocessing
import time
import sys

class worker(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, valobj):
        super(worker,self).__init__()
        self.val = valobj

    def run(self):
        while True:
            print("Worker report: val is %s" % (self.val.value))
            time.sleep(self.val.value)


valobj = multiprocessing.Value('i', 5)
subproc = worker(valobj)
subproc.start()
while True:
    new_val =  sys.stdin.readline().rstrip()
    if new_val:
        valobj.value = int(new_val)
    print("Main report: val is %s" %(valobj.value))
```

This code have desired behavior:

```
$ ./test.py
Worker report: val is 5
1
Main report: val is 1

Main report: val is 1

Main report: val is 1
Worker report: val is 1
Worker report: val is 1
Worker report: val is 1
3
Main report: val is 3
Worker report: val is 3
Worker report: val is 3
```

Comment: Not really a good answer if you don't emphasize and explain the difference.

Comment: Yep, forgot it.

Answer (score 0):

Multiprocessing spawns a **new** process copying the current process (and its memmory state) you are into, so you can not access that new process from your current process, you should comunicate them for doing so.

Take a look at [sharing state](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) or [exchanging objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) between processes.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid using shared variables. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @J.Doe, yep, you can use threading instead of processing anyway depending on what you have to do.

Comment: Threads is non-killable, as i know. If thread hangs on 'readline()', i can't do anything with them.

Comment: @J.Doe, it will hang on readline since it is a blocking call, you can catch an exception if it happens and set some sort of flag to true to make the main thread spawn another reading thread. In that way it will not work diferent from another process. Also when your processes will exit it will kill the thread too.

Comment: Yes, but problem in that, threads have to 'readline' on PTY unpredictable amount of time. During this blocking call, main program can decide to close this thread. And this is a problem because this blocked thread cannot be joined or killed.

Comment: @J.Doe, the thread will be killed once the main program (process) exits. You dont have to wait for it to be joined. **Depending on the thread task** could be enough i think

Answer (score 0):

If you are OK to use `threading` instead of `multiprocessing`, Try the below code.
I just change `multiprocessing` to `threading` and set `daemon` attribute of the thread object as `True`.

> ### daemon
>
> boolean value indicating whether this thread is a daemon
>   thread (True) or not (False). This must be set before start() is
>   called, otherwise RuntimeError is raised. Its initial value is
>   inherited from the creating thread; the main thread is not a daemon
>   thread and therefore all threads created in the main thread default to
>   daemon = False.
>
> The entire Python program exits when no alive non-daemon threads are
>   left.

In short, If your `worker thread` is set as `daemon=True` and the `main thread` exit, the `worker thread` also exit because there is no `non-daemon thread` alive(`main thread` must be `non-daemon thread`).

You can simply exit entire program by `KeyboardInterrupt`(Ctrl+c).

```
import threading
import time
import sys


class worker(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, val):
        super(worker, self).__init__()
        self.val = val

    def update_val(self, val):
        if val.isdigit():
            self.val = int(val)
            print("self.val now is %s" % (self.val))
        else:
            print("val should be digit")

    def run(self):
        while True:
            print("Worker report: val is %s" % (self.val))
            time.sleep(self.val)


subproc = worker(10)
subproc.daemon = True    # By setting daemon, the threading will be killed when main thread exit.
subproc.start()
while True:
    new_val = sys.stdin.readline().rstrip()
    if new_val:
        subproc.update_val(new_val)
    print("Main report: val is %s" % (subproc.val))
```